# Updating of SharePoint List using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I am creating some web pages using HTML and JavaScript and the end result has to be uploaded into a given SharePoint list.  I found a tons of details of how to do this, but right from day one I am stuck in only one issue.  I have tried all the possible combinations that is given in hte below link.

[Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136592/typeerror-sp-clientcontext-is-undefined)

But end of the day I continue to have the same error.  'SP' is undefined.

To give you a little back ground.  I have created web pages and the webpage is being stored on a SharePoint site in shared folders.  Now a hyperlink is provided to the end user to click on the link that directly open the given stored web page in the shared folder of the given SharePoint site.  Given below is the code.  I know I might be missing something really small.

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function preparePage() 
{ //Hide Execution lead
if( document.getElementById("ExeLead").style.display=='none' ){
 document.getElementById("ExeLead").style.display = '';
}
else {
 document.getElementById("ExeLead").style.display = 'none';
}
getDetails();
}

function getParam(name)//to get details that is passed via url
{  
 name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");  
 var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";  
 var regex = new RegExp( regexS );  
 var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
 results[1] = results[1].replace(/%20/g," ");
 if(results == null)
  return "NA";  
 else    
  return results[1];
 }

function getDetails()//extract info form URL
{
 frmUpdates.txtBIStatus.value=getParam("Status");
 frmUpdates.txtBINumber.value=getParam("BINo");     
}

var siteUrl = 'Url to the SharePoint site';
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", createListItem());
/*if(!SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createListItem, 'sp.js')){ 
LoadSodByKey('sp.js');
};*/
//LoadSodByKey('sp.js');


function createListItem() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

oListItem.set_item('IdeaRef', 'My New Item');
oListItem.set_item('Status', 'Hello World!');

oListItem.update();

clientContext.load(oListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
 alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
 alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</Script>
<title>Tool</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="preparePage()">

<form name="frmUpdates">
<table border="5" width="444">
<tr>
 <td width="344" height="35" colspan="2">&nbsp;Tool</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="144" height="35">Bright Idea #:</td>
 <td width="300">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtBINumber" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="144" height="35">Bright Idea Status</td>
 <td width="300">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtBIStatus" size="40"></td>
</tr> 
<tr id="ExeLead">
 <td width="144" height="35">Assign Execution Lead</td>
 <td width="300" height="35">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtExecutionLead" size="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="144" height="35" colspan="2">Comments</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="444" height="150" colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea rows="8" cols="48" name="txtComments" from="frmComments">Enter your comments here....</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="444" height="35" colspan="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit" onclick="createListItem()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>



</body> 

</html>
```

Note I am using Notepad to write this code and using Internet Explorer's F12 to check on how the code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Download Notepad++ atleast :)

Just so I understand correctly. Does the user have access to the SharePoint site? If you just upload a CLEAN HTML file(?) with some javascript to a Shared folder and share that to a user (that doesn't have access to the site), this is not possible. The SP.js is loaded within SharePoint.

If you create a page layout with this html (inside all the elements Sharepoint needs), you can use the script also, but the users still need access to the site and the list.

I would recommend creating an SharePoint add-in instead tho.

**EDIT:**

I've tried your code inside an content editor web part on my dev site (without head/body), and it worked.

This does not solve your problem but you should make an click event (with jQuery) on the button, else it will create a list item when the page load, even if you have specified on the element createListItem() when you clicked the button, this will run anyway because of: SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", yourfunc).

```
$("#buttonId").click(function() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", createListItem());
});
```

or create a new function for SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", createListItem()); that you use in onclick.

You could also try replacing

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

with

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

If the list is on the same level as the page library, then you don't have to specify the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing it and I have full access to this SharePoint site.  The webpage is kept on a SharePoint site.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Ok. Could you try just write SP. in the console in dev tools (F12 in IE) and see if you get any options?